# Facebook Fan Page Graph Api Event Import from non managed pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there way how to import events from non managed fan page?

The problem is that I can get from the database info about event, if I know eid of the event. But I can't get the list of eids in event_member table, it returns empty data.
So I know the uid of the fan page, but I am not able to get their eids for events, to get them.
I would like to make place, where you can see all local events in one place. 
And there are two ways, one to copy it by hand and second ... :)

Anybody know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get **recent** public events using Graph API.  For example, these public events for a Page I do not own or manage:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=79116358489%2Fevents

Seems that events too far in the past are not included in the query.
The query results seem to be limited the last 2 weeks.

Comment: Finally I figured it in another way. But this seems very good, I think I will use this method later. Thaaaank you :)

Comment: I tried it now and it seems not to work. I really dont know, in your case it is function like a charm, but when I try another page e.g. ID:10150542773602452 if returns error :(

Comment: Tried on two pages and got same errror result :(

Comment: Petr, 10150542773602452 seems to be a photo.  Not a page nor an event